# bitter intensity

Tags: meaning, collocation

What is the meaning of **bitter intensity**? For example:

> Here and there we find a slight suggestion of the bitter intensity of
>   the poet X.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the phrase has any idiomatic significance. Its meaning is derived from the words constituting it.

Bitter has a negative connotation. For example, if we say that A and B are bitter enemies, it indicates a heightened level of animosity between them. Bitterness can also indicate cynicism or contempt. For example, one might say that losing his wife to a doctor's negligence has made XYZ bitter towards the medical profession.

[Merriam-Webster:Bitter](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bitter)

Intensity implies ardency, fervour or passion.

[Merriam-Webster:Intensity](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intensity)

Therefore, it is my guess that bitter intensity of a poet would indicate a generally negative outlook that the poet has harped upon with great fervor. In other words, saying that a person is bitterly intense implies that he is someone who might be persistently negative or bleak in his worldview.

However, this is only my interpretation.

Comment: Your first sentence is enough to answer. In fact, that makes the question a NARQ.